# Jquery Jqgrid + Asp.Net don't work too easily?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jqgrid

I have been struggling quite a bit to get this JQgrid to work with Asp.Net.

I found asp.net samples online...but if I modify them according to my database,it flops.

Do I need to change the DataTable to JSON functions as well?

Out of my search,I found these 2 articles getting me pretty close...
http://arahuman.blogspot.com/2009/06/jqgrid-using-mvc-json-and-datatable.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/jqGrid.aspx

But then,it just doesn't work if I try a sample project with my own data table.

Can someone give me a hand please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ASP.NET we have created a server-side component, with programming experience / APIs very similar to the stock asp:GridView control. Note that the server-side component is not free though.

You can see more than 30 examples of jqGrid ASP.NET here

http://www.trirand.net/demo.aspx

and download the component and sample projects.

Rumen Stankov
jqGrid

Answer (score 0):

Have you made changes to the GridDemo.Home.GridDemo.setupGrid to match your database columns.

Jqgrid needs the setupGrid to be called with columns and other setting as per your preference.

If you post exact problem faced someone can help out.